# FitNesse not invoking overloading method

Tags: java, junit, fitnesse-slim

I made a wrapper class `MyClassFixture` for a pojo `MyClass` by extending it, to made the initialization of its fields more user friendly. Eg. I want to use my own date format on wiki pages, and parse that date in the overloading setters. So instead of invoking `setWorkDay(long millis)` from `MyClass` I want to invoke `setWorkDay(String formatedDate)` from `MyClassFixture` and parse the formatedDate string and then invoke `setWorkDay(long)` of the parent `MyClass`.

This is working nicely when I run the test from the wiki page, but not working when I run it with JUnit runner. The error message I got:

```
Can't convert 2016-03-05 to long. Tried to invoke: foo.bar.MyClass.setWorkDay(long) -> void. On instance of: foo.bar.MyClassFixture
```

I've tried it with different String arguments, but always the setWorkDay(long) method gets invoked.
Why is this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer in FitNesse code. It is matching the method name and the number of arguments, but not the type of arguments.

The difference between the run with fitnesse-standalone.jar and with JUnit runner was caused by using different JRE implementations (IBM vs. Oracle). `instance.getClass().getMethods()` returned Methods in different order, FitNesse picks the last one.

So the safe solution is not overloading but using different method names.